# CompletableFuture exceptionally() and handle() swallowing RuntimeException?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, exception, completable-future

I have the following:

```
cflst.addAll(asList(
            supplyAsync(() -> mytask.getComp("comp"), executor)
                    .thenAccept(comp -> helper.mapStuff(comp))
                    .exceptionally(ex -> {
                        sout("Some Error");  // Never print
                        return null;
                    })
                    .handle((comp, throwable) -> {
                        sout("Error here" + comp); //always prints regarless of exception
                        return null;
                    }),

    ...

    ));

 CompletableFuture.allOf(cflst.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```

And `MyTask.getComp` method

```
 CompX getComp(String id) {
     client.getData(id);
  }
```

`Client.getData()`

```
 SomeX getData(String id) {
    throw new MyCustomRuntimeException("Blew Up");
 }
```

I thought it when the exception is thrown in `myComp` method, the `exceptionally()` block gets the exception. But it does not seem to.

Also, regardless of exception, `handle()` always gets called !?!?!

I want to be able to catch any exception and handle it as needed (Either rethrow or swallow).

**Update**

When I catch the exception in `getComp` method and then re-throw it, `exceptionally` block gets executed. But not sure why it does not gets executed, when exception is thrown one more level down at `getData` method?

Comment: Is `getCommp()` a typo in your post? (Always copy/paste code, never retype)

Comment: Yes, it is. Fixed it.

Comment: That `handle()` always gets called is not the issue, that's to be expected; it should print "Error here: null" because `exceptionally()` should get called beforehand and set the result to `null`. The question is why the message in `exceptionally`is not output; what is `sout()`, maybe it suppresses it somehow?

Comment: I see you have accepted an answer, what was the issue in the end? The answer does not explain why your `exceptionally()` function was not executed…

Comment: Re the 'Never print' issue. I saw a similar problem in Android with a Toast in .exceptionally. The same Toast inside a block to run on UI thread it works fine. From checking the logs the exceptionally always appeared to be on a different thread when I examined it.  It's not as simple as it looks however as the Toast seems to crash silently and no code in exceptionally executes after it, but no other execution seems affected, plus updating a TextView in the UI inside exceptionally works fine. Not got to the bottom of this yet, but curious if you found the root of your 'Never Print' issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are composing `CompletableFuture`s sequentially.

After `.exceptionally()`, you get a future that yields `null` instead of throwing an exception.  Therefore, the subsequent `.handle()` will never observe an exception.

If you want `.handle()` to get the same exception, you must call it on the same future where you call `.exception()`. For instance, use a variable to store the future you get after `.thenAccept()` and then compose `.exceptionally()` and `.handle()` on it, instead of sequentially.

However, you should choose between `.exceptionally()` and `.handle()`:

- `.exceptionally()` is usually used to return a default value instead of letting an exception through
- `.handle()` is usually used to log, transform and/or wrap the exception like a `catch` block; don't forget to rethrow if you want the exception to go through

For cleanup actions like a `finally` block, `.whenComplete()` is more appropriate.

Comment: OP's issue is not that `handle` doesn't get the exception, it's that only `handle` gets the exception and `exceptionally` is not called at all.

Comment: OP updated saying exception thrown directly from `getComp()` goes through `exceptionally()`. I can't replicate the OP's observations. As you commented directly in the question, maybe `sout()` is doing something, like throwing. Nonetheless, I decided to contribute, to describe the choice between `exceptionally`, `whenComplete` and `handle`.

Answer (score 1):

The stage created by `handle()` method is always executed regardless of exception occurs or not, whereas `exceptionally()` stage is only executed when there's an exception.

I couldn't reproduce your error, `exceptionally` block executes for me whenever the exception is not caught.

In my opinion, you should use either `handle` or `exceptionally`.

`handle()` method enables you to provide a default value on exception and `exceptionally()` method is similar to handle but less verbose